# How to use regex pattern to match longer string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a text string, similar to below example,

> I have 5-6 year of experience with 2-3 years experience in Java

I have used this below regex syntax to match it,

```
import re

pattern = '\d{1}-\d{1} year'
[(m.start(0), m.end(0),'Experience') for m in re.finditer(pattern, string)]

# results
5-6 year
2-3 year (In this case it's missing out the 's'.)
```

How to modify this pattern to also match 'years and year' which every is longest?

Comment: Use`'\d{1}-\d{1} years?'`

Comment: What if one has more than 9 years?

Comment: @DYZ I also need to extract if it's more than 9 years as well.

Comment: Try the following: `\d{1}-\d{1}\s*year[s]*`

Comment: @user_12, use `'\d+-\d+ years?'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an optional "s": `'\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s*years?'`. I also changed `'\d{1}'` to `'\d{1,2}'` which means "one or two digits" (it's hard to imagine someone has more than 99 years of experience), and replaced one space with `'\s*'` - any number of spaces, including no spaces.

Comment: what does `?` do in this pattern?

Comment: Just as I said: it means "optional."

Comment: @user_12, it makes trailing `s` optional.

Comment: I made some extra changes to handle two-digit numbers.

Comment: @DYZ Is there a way to also catch pattern like `2-3years and 2-3year` without space.

Comment: See the latest update.